# aspnetcore is missing from Codegen Options in SwaggerHub

Tags: swagger, codegen

for me, aspnetcore is missing from Codegen Options in SwaggerHub.

Am I making some simple mistake?
I just want to generate server stub from existing openapi file.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

figured out myself - when creating an new API in SwaggerHub, you should go with OpenAPI Version 2.0 , not 3.0 if you want to have Server Stub generation option.